# ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) ResponseError: code=412, message=Unknown top level field in manifest: runtime

Tags: node.js, deployment, yaml, gcloud

I get error when running

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments create my-deployment --config app.yaml
```

Content of app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the command to deploy to [Google Cloud Deployment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/) but with a configuration file for the [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/). You need to (depending on what you're trying to do) either use the `gcloud app deploy` command, or create a Deployment Manager configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer